# How to change image when scrolling down a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed navbar and want to change logo img when scrolling down for better contrast. I'm using bootstrap. Maybe using a if statement?

```
   $('#mainNav').affix({
    offset: ({
        top: 100
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use an event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",()=>{
  if(((window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0))>300){
      //replace image if scrolled more than 300
  }else{
     //replace with other image
 }},false);
```